# How to get images in my electron app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron

i am creating a react app which is using webpack to bundle all its required files to build folder. Here is the folder structure under my build folder after i build the application.

```
-build
   --image
     --- myImage1.jpg
     --- myImage2.png
   --static
     --- css
     --- js
     --- media
   --asset-manifest.json
   --icon.ico
   --index.html
   --main.js
```

when i run this application as a browser application the images are loaded correctly. 
But when i use "electron ." to run the application the images are not shown in my application. main.js is the entry point. 
I am using yarn as my package manager.

Should i re arrange the folder structure to get the images available in my electron app?
How shall i get the images available in my electron app. thanks in advance.